# Spaces: visualization in menubar, and arbitrary keybinding for 'goto next space'

Tags: spaces, menu-bar

I'm looking for a tool or tools to 
(1) switch to the next (or previous) space using an arbitrary keybinding, rathern than the modifier+arrow keys allowed in the preferences, and
(2) show a (very) small preview of the windows in Spaces in the menubar.

I've been using Desktop Manager to do this since before they were called spaces.  Unfortunately Desktop Manager is PowerPC-only and is not being maintained; I'd like a more modern solution.  I'm much more interested in solving the first problem; specifically I'd like to have ctrl-command-n to move me to the next space, and ctrl-command-p to go to the previous space.

Any quick solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a shortcut via Keyboard Shortcuts. Remember to tick the checkbox too!

[image: Move Spaces shortcuts]

Comment: Thanks, that was simple!  Now that I see a solution available in Lion, I'll upgrade.